# If any digit of a given 4-digit number is deleted, the resulting 3-digit number is a divisor of the original number.

Tags: combinatorics

If any digit of a given 4-digit number is deleted, the resulting 3-digit number is a divisor of the original number. How many 4-digit numbers have this property?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: It isn't the easiest thing in the world to come up with a written argument, but this is easy to code.  You have $1100,1200,1500,2200,2400,3300,3600,4400,4800,5500,6600,7700,8800,9900$ for a total of $14$ such four-digit numbers (*more if you allow leading zeroes*).

Comment: @JMoravitz Now for $400$-digit numbers...

Comment: @WaliWaqar I have posted Moravitz's solution as a Community Answer. Perhaps you could accept it, so that we can clear this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $4$-digit number $n = abcd$, where $a,b,c$ and $d$ are digits, satisfies

$$n = 1000a + 100b + 10c + d.$$

Your condition is equivalent to

$$k_d = (100a + 10b + c) | n$$
$$k_c = (100a + 10b + d) | n$$
$$k_b = (100a + 10c + d) | n$$
$$k_a = (100b + 10c + d) | n$$

Now, notice that $n - 10k_d = d$;
because $k_d$ divides the LHS, it must also divide $d$.
But $k_d \geqslant 100$ and $0\leqslant d \leqslant 9$, from which it follows that $d = 0$.

Then, $n - 10k_c = 10c$; 
because $k_c$ divides the LHS, it must also divide $10c$.
But $k_c \geqslant 100$ and $0\leqslant 10c \leqslant 90$, from which it follows that $c$ is also $0$.

$n$ is hence of the form $ab00$, and the conditions for $k_d$ and $k_c$ are satisfied in this situation.
We are left with

- $b$ is deleted: $a | 10a + b$, which simplifies to $a | b$.
- $a$ is deleted: $b | 10a + b$, which simplies to $b | 10a$.

The question hence boils down to how many pairs of integers $1\leqslant a \leqslant 9$ and $0\leqslant b \leqslant 9$ satisfy $a|b$ and $b | 10a$.

We find:

- If $a = 1$, then $a|b$ removes no possibilities for $b$.
  Then, $b | 10 \implies b = 1, 2, 5$.
- If $a = 2$, then $a|b \implies b \in \{0,2,4,6,8\}$.
  Then, $b|20 \implies b = 2, 4$.
- If $a = 3$, then $a|b \implies b \in \{0,3,6,9\}$.
  Then, $b|30 \implies b = 3, 6$.
- If $a = 4$, then $a|b \implies b \in \{0,4,8\}$.
  Then, $b|40 \implies b = 4, 8$.
- For values of $a \geqslant 5$, we have $a|b \implies b \in \{0,a\}$ and then $b|10a \implies b = a$ is the only possibility.

This gives us a total of $3+2+2+2+5 = 14$ possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

There is no obvious elegant way of doing this by hand. But it is easy to write a short computer program to find all the numbers. You get:

1100,1200,1500,2200,2400,3300,3600,4400,4800,5500,6600,7700,8800,9900

(assuming leading zeros are not allowed).

So the answer is 14.